# deploying python code to heroku not working

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have added the buildpack for python, it works.

But when i do a git push it doesnt work.

I get the below error all the time.

```
(venv) D:\Projects\ecommerce\clone\cut_veggies>heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
Buildpack set. Next release on cutveggie will use heroku/python.
Run git push heroku master to create a new release using this buildpack.

(venv) D:\Projects\ecommerce\clone\cut_veggies>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 308, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (305/305), done.
Writing objects: 100% (308/308), 410.14 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 308 (delta 193), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-        buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to cutveggie.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/cutveggie.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/cutveggie.git'
```

Can anyone tell what i am missing?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Heroku/python failed to detect set buildpack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282911/heroku-python-failed-to-detect-set-buildpack), take a look and add your `requirements.txt`, you can create it with `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, try it out.

Comment: Yes i followed that. requirements.txt is created using pip freeze but still getting same error.

Comment: I have requirements.txt but still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem with my application too. Adding a `requirements.txt` file with the dependencies to the root of the project solved it. Check [here](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) for more details. You can check [here](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/master/requirements.txt) for an example too.

Comment: I have requirements.txt but still doesnt solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I too had (and still have) this problem of not being able to push the app live through Heroku CLI.

A fix I found for this was to log on to Heroku using a browser and link your GitHub account and repo to the app. Then deploy this through GitHub.

They offer two possibilities. One is manual deployment where you deploy manually through the website after running thorough tests. Another is automatic deployment where the app is deployed as soon as you push your changes to the branch you linked to the app.

I have been using this ever since Windows decided to go crazy on me and prevent me from pushing the app to heroku master.